# Need assistance! printing previous user input data from a loop

Tags: java, loops, printf

Hey new guy here need assistance in my problem! i need to print previous user input data from a loop the problem is that it prints the last data the user inputs. Please shed some light my mind is getting dark. I appreciate all of you answers. Thank you!
My program: (Sorry if it's disgusting af)

```
package activity2;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Activity2 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] name = {"Milk","Juice","Energy drink","Water","Softdrink","Beer","Wine","Coffee"};
        int[] pnum = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
        double[] price = {300,100,220,120,200,350,400,130};
        String[] list = {"Enter product #: ","Enter quantity: ","Sub-total: "};
        double sum=0,q=0,v,s;
        int sum2=0, w;
        String z = "";
        int x,c = 0;
        System.out.println("            Product Information");
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Name                        Price");
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(pnum[0]+"."+name[0]+"                         "+price[0]);
        System.out.println(pnum[1]+"."+name[1]+"                        "+price[1]);
        System.out.println(pnum[2]+"."+name[2]+"                 "+price[2]);
        System.out.println(pnum[3]+"."+name[3]+"                        "+price[3]);
        System.out.println(pnum[4]+"."+name[4]+"                    "+price[4]);
        System.out.println(pnum[5]+"."+name[5]+"                         "+price[5]);
        System.out.println(pnum[6]+"."+name[6]+"                         "+price[6]);
        System.out.println(pnum[7]+"."+name[7]+"                       "+price[7]);
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
        do{
        System.out.print("Enter number of products: ");
        int a = sc.nextInt();

        for (x=0;x<a;x++){

            System.out.print(list[0]);
            w = sc.nextInt();
            sum2 =w;
            System.out.print(list[1]);
            s = sc.nextDouble();
            q = s * price[w];
            System.out.println(list[2]+q);
            sum +=q;

        }
        System.out.println("Total: " + sum);
        System.out.print("Do you want another transaction?(y/n):");
        z = sc.next();
        x = a;
        v = q;
        System.out.println("Transaction Details"); 
        for(int t=0; t<x; t++){
         System.out.println(pnum[sum2]+"."+name[sum2]+"---------"+v);
                 }
         System.out.println("TOTAL: " + sum);
         System.out.print("Enter cash amount: ");
         double i = sc.nextDouble();
         if(sum>i){
             System.out.println("Cash is insuffecient! Please try again:");
             System.out.print("Enter cash amount: ");
             i = sc.nextDouble();
         }
         double tc = i - sum;
         System.out.print("Cash change"+tc);
        }
        while(z.equals("y")); 


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to use a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html).

(direct quote below from link)

> "StringBuilder objects are like String objects, except that they can be modified. Internally, these objects are treated like variable-length arrays that contain a sequence of characters. At any point, the length and content of the sequence can be changed through method invocations."

You can save data with StringBuilder, then print everything all at one time. This makes life a little easier too ;-)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] name = {"Milk","Juice","Energy drink","Water","Softdrink","Beer","Wine","Coffee"};
        int[] pnum = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
        double[] price = {300,100,220,120,200,350,400,130};
        String[] list = {"Enter product #: ","Enter quantity: ","Sub-total: "};
        double sum=0,q=0,v,s;
        int sum2=0, w;
        String z = "";
        int x,c = 0;
        System.out.println("            Product Information");
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Name                        Price");
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(pnum[0]+"."+name[0]+"                         "+price[0]);
        System.out.println(pnum[1]+"."+name[1]+"                        "+price[1]);
        System.out.println(pnum[2]+"."+name[2]+"                 "+price[2]);
        System.out.println(pnum[3]+"."+name[3]+"                        "+price[3]);
        System.out.println(pnum[4]+"."+name[4]+"                    "+price[4]);
        System.out.println(pnum[5]+"."+name[5]+"                         "+price[5]);
        System.out.println(pnum[6]+"."+name[6]+"                         "+price[6]);
        System.out.println(pnum[7]+"."+name[7]+"                       "+price[7]);
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
        do{
        System.out.print("Enter number of products: ");
        int a = sc.nextInt();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (x=0;x<a;x++) {

            System.out.print(list[0]);
            w = sc.nextInt();
            sum2 =w;
            System.out.print(list[1]);
            s = sc.nextDouble();
            q = s * price[w];
            System.out.println(list[2]+q);
            sb.append(pnum[sum2]+"."+name[sum2]+"---------"+q + "\n");
            sum +=q;

        }
        System.out.println("Total: " + sum);
        System.out.print("Do you want another transaction?(y/n):");
        z = sc.next();
        x = a;
        v = q;
        System.out.println("Transaction Details"); 
        System.out.println(sb);
         System.out.println("TOTAL: " + sum);
         System.out.print("Enter cash amount: ");
         double i = sc.nextDouble();
         if(sum>i){
             System.out.println("Cash is insuffecient! Please try again:");
             System.out.print("Enter cash amount: ");
             i = sc.nextDouble();
         }
         double tc = i - sum;
         System.out.print("Cash change"+tc);
        }
        while(z.equals("y")); 


    }
```

This will give you the output you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks alot man. it worked! i haven't tackled stringbuilder yet so i'll read on it. thank you again. :)

Comment: @JustaUser69 Please accept if this answer was the most useful for you. Accept by checking the check mark. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you're not saving each entry. If you want to be able to print it back at the end you need to do this. I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but this should at least give you an idea on what you need to do in order to be able to print out transaction details. Also you really need to name your variables a lot better.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Activity2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] name = {"Milk","Juice","Energy drink","Water","Softdrink","Beer","Wine","Coffee"};
    int[] pnum = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    double[] price = {300,100,220,120,200,350,400,130};
    String[] list = {"Enter product #: ","Enter quantity: ","Sub-total: "};
    double sum=0,q=0,v,s;
    int sum2=0, w;
    String z = "";
    int x,c = 0;
    System.out.println("            Product Information");
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Name                        Price");
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println(pnum[0]+"."+name[0]+"                         "+price[0]);
    System.out.println(pnum[1]+"."+name[1]+"                        "+price[1]);
    System.out.println(pnum[2]+"."+name[2]+"                 "+price[2]);
    System.out.println(pnum[3]+"."+name[3]+"                        "+price[3]);
    System.out.println(pnum[4]+"."+name[4]+"                    "+price[4]);
    System.out.println(pnum[5]+"."+name[5]+"                         "+price[5]);
    System.out.println(pnum[6]+"."+name[6]+"                         "+price[6]);
    System.out.println(pnum[7]+"."+name[7]+"                       "+price[7]);
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
    do{
    System.out.print("Enter number of products: ");
    int a = sc.nextInt();
    int[] productNum = new int[a];
    String[] products = new String[a];
    double[] prices = new double[a];
    for (x=0;x<a;x++){

        System.out.print(list[0]);
        w = sc.nextInt();
        sum2 =w;
        System.out.print(list[1]);
        s = sc.nextDouble();
        q = s * price[w];
        System.out.println(list[2]+q);
        sum +=q;
        productNum[x] = w;
        products[x] = name[w];
        prices[x] = q;

    }
    System.out.println("Total: " + sum);
    System.out.print("Do you want another transaction?(y/n):");
    z = sc.next();
    x = a;
    v = q;
    System.out.println("Transaction Details"); 
    for(int t=0; t<x; t++){
     System.out.println(productNum[t]+"."+products[t]+"---------"+prices[t]);
             }
     System.out.println("TOTAL: " + sum);
     System.out.print("Enter cash amount: ");
     double i = sc.nextDouble();
     if(sum>i){
         System.out.println("Cash is insuffecient! Please try again:");
         System.out.print("Enter cash amount: ");
         i = sc.nextDouble();
     }
     double tc = i - sum;
     System.out.print("Cash change"+tc);
    }
    while(z.equals("y")); 


  }
}
```

Comment: yeah i actually did this and because my variable names we're messed up i completely got alot of variables for printing wrong and i discarded this method. xD thanks man.